# What is the default TCP keep alive in redis

Tags: redis

What is the default tcp-keepalive for redis 3 if i don't specify? i commented the tcp-keepalive option in redis.conf file.

```
# A reasonable value for this option is 60 seconds.
#tcp-keepalive 0
```

Answer (score 4):

The default is 0.

You can verify this by running `CONFIG GET tcp-keepalive`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET tcp-keepalive
1) "tcp-keepalive"
2) "0"
```

or looking at [the source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/f0b168e8944af41c4161249040f01ece227cfc0c/src/server.h#L113).

Comment: Thanks vaultah.  What about redis-2.6.7?

Answer (score 4):

Depends.

["…](https://redis.io/topics/clients)

TCP keepalive
Recent versions of Redis (3.2 or greater) have TCP keepalive (SO_KEEPALIVE socket option) enabled by default and set to about 300 seconds. This option is useful in order to detect dead peers (clients that cannot be reached even if they look connected). Moreover, if there is network equipment between clients and servers that need to see some traffic in order to take the connection open, the option will prevent unexpected connection closed events.

…"